# Provisioning Profile listing in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I went to Xcode\Preferences\Accounts.  But I could not find the next step. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in here, but you probably don't have a account yet. If you click on the + you can add an Apple ID.

Then, in the details of your Apple account you will be able to see your provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Use [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone%20configuration%20utility) on Xcode 5.0 + to manage your provisioning profiles directly.